How to parse the <coordinate-like> input parameteres with xparse?
I haved confranted the question when first exploring the arguments parsed by the xparse package.
The requirement I want to get is that:
In the document of xparse, I found different types of mandatory and optional arguments like o,d,r etc. But I get a little confused with delimited arguments.
I found the link here Environment with coordinate-like arguments, but I couldn't make sense.
In details, now I want two NewDocumentCommand \cmdfirst \cmdsecond
[FIRST] for the \cmdfirst, I want to parse two pairs of numbers below. I means that I want to type:
\cmdfirst[(1,2)]{(3,4)}

Then I can get the number (1,2,3,4) displayed on the pdf. In a word, I wonder the arguments definition \NewDocumentCommand{\cmdfirst}{??}{(#1,#2,#3,#4)}
[SECOND] then for the \cmdsecond, I wonder that if I can use it aw below: when I type:
\cmdsecond[7,8]{9,10}

Then I can get the number (7,8,9,10) displayed on the pdf. I just curious about the arguments settings.
Thanks a lot!

Can you provide a complete example of how you plan to use this? If you plan to use this inside a drawing environment, it matters which one you're using ... picture, tikzpicture, pspicture, metapost etc. in tikz, for example, you can easily feed in a list of coordinates and have tikz connect them, because pgf utilities have special handling for just this kind of case. but then you don't need \NewDocumentCommand. NB in contrast, \NewDocumentCommand \cmd won't be expandable so using it inside a \path, say, would be problematic.

In tikzpicture, I know that actually I can use the command such as \draw (1,2) -- (2,3) -- (3,4) -- (5,6); to connect without newcommand, the usage it's  just an example in my perspect of usage scenario, the second problem is just because my curiousity, and the parameters can be passed in Python like *args and **kwargs, I am curious about that whether it can be achieved in TeX.

If the second one is a little problematic, we can just focus on the first problem! Thanks!

it isn't the first versus the second. \NewDocumentCommand makes a command which isn't expandable and you can't use it like \path [draw] \cmd[(0,0)]{(1,1)}; in a tikzpicture because pgf uses a customised parser which needs to see particular things. (& you can't do \expandafter etc. or \ExpandArgs ... if \cmd is not expandable. (well, you can, but it won't help.) so you need to give an example of how you want to use this and ask how to do that.

May be the usage scenario  I put forward misunderstanding, my focus is not on the pgf, I just wonder the xparse package's usage. I will change the description above.

Oh, then just look at usrguide.pdf (texdoc usrguide) for details of the argument specifiers you can use. For the list, look at Argument Processors > SplitList.

ok! thanks a lot!

Although I consult the docs with \SplitList, but it may stored the macros altogether in #1, then it will be process by \ProcessList, which couldn't display in term seperately as (#1,#2), a little confusing  (；′⌒`)

Note that you haven't asked anything about delimited arguments ....

Note that you've not asked anything about delimited arguments except the standard cases of optional arguments in square brackets. The fact that you've used parentheses within an argument doesn't make those parentheses delimiters. A delimited case involving parentheses would be something like
\NewDocumentCommand \cmdzeroth { d () } { ... }
...
\cmdzeroth(abc)

The cases you've asked about involve only the standard optional/mandatory syntax.
The second case is straightforward as we just need to concatenate the arguments and insert the surrounding parentheses and separating comma, if applicable.
\NewDocumentCommand \cmdsecond {o m}% an optional arg followed by a required one
{%
  (%
  \IfValueT{#1}{#1,}% we only want the comma if the optional arg is present
  #2)%
}

\IfValueT tests for the presence of an o type argument i.e. an optional argument with no default.
For example,
\cmdsecond[8,9,10]{11,12}

\cmdsecond{13,14,15}

typesets (8,9,10,11,12) and (13,14,15).
The first case is trickier because we need to remove the parentheses from the arguments first. We can do this with an argument processor, but we need a custom one.
\NewDocumentCommand \cmdfirst { >{\rmparentheses} o >{\rmparentheses} m}
{%
  (%
  \IfValueT{#1}{#1,}%
  #2)%
}

So \rmparentheses needs to strip the outer parentheses1.
The simplest option is to assume the user is careful and will only give us input in the correct format. In that case, we can assume the argument(s) have the exact form (<stuff>) and remove the parentheses using a delimited macro either dropping down to TeX level or using expl3.
It is officially better to use expl3, but we'd need to use 'weird' arguments or make things more complicated2 and TeX is simpler.
\makeatletter
\def\rmparenthesesaux(#1){\def\ProcessedArgument{#1}}
\def\rmparentheses#1{\rmparenthesesaux#1}
\makeatother

For example,
\cmdfirst[(1,2)]{(3,4)}

\cmdfirst{(5,6,7)}

typesets (1,2,3,4) and (5,6,7).
However, user input is not necessarily so well-behaved3, so it might be good to be more careful here. We assume we may have spurious spaces before and/or after the arguments and that the opening and/or closing parenthesis may be missing.
\TrimSpaces will strip any spaces we don't want. We then need an argument processor, \RmParentheses, to strip any opening parenthesis from the left and any closing parenthesis from the right.
\NewDocumentCommand \cmdthird {  >{\RmParentheses}  >{\TrimSpaces} o >{\RmParentheses} >{\TrimSpaces} m}
{%
  (%
  \IfValueT{#1}{#1,}%
  #2)%
}

This time we use expl3 because it is provides various functions for manipulating token lists (_tl variables) which make the task simpler.
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \RmParentheses #1
{

There's a special function for testing the first token in a token list i.e. the list's 'head'.
  \tl_if_head_eq_meaning:eNTF { #1  } (
  {

If the first token is an opening parenthesis, we set a scratch variable to the list's 'tail' which is, basically, everything except the head and not, as the name might suggest, only the last token.
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_tail:n { #1 } }
  }{

If it isn't, we use the whole thing.
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  }

There's no function to test only the last token in the list2, but there is a function to reverse it. So we reverse the list
  \tl_reverse:N \l_tmpa_tl

and then see if the new 'head' is a closing parenthesis.
  \tl_if_head_eq_meaning:eNTF { \l_tmpa_tl  } )
  {

If so, we keep the tail in a second scratch variable.
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \tl_tail:N \l_tmpa_tl }
  }{

If not, we keep the lot.
    \tl_set_eq:NN \l_tmpb_tl   \l_tmpa_tl 
  }

We've stripped the parentheses, but we've reversed the token list while doing so, so we need to reverse again.
  \tl_reverse:N \l_tmpb_tl

Now we just return the content of the scratch variable,
  \tl_set_eq:NN \ProcessedArgument \l_tmpb_tl
}

and we're done.
\ExplSyntaxOff

For example,
\cmdthird[ (16,17)]{(18,19) }

\cmdthird{   20,21 }

\cmdthird[22,23)   ]{ (24,25,26  }

typesets (16,17,18,19), (20,21) and (22,23,24,25,26).

Complete code:
\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/723328/
\NewDocumentCommand \cmdsecond {o m}% an optional arg followed by a required one
{%
  (%
  \IfValueT{#1}{#1,}% we only want the comma if the optional arg is present
  #2)%
}
\NewDocumentCommand \cmdfirst { >{\rmparentheses} o >{\rmparentheses} m}
{%
  (%
  \IfValueT{#1}{#1,}%
  #2)%
}
\NewDocumentCommand \cmdthird {  >{\RmParentheses}  >{\TrimSpaces} o >{\RmParentheses} >{\TrimSpaces} m}
{%
  (%
  \IfValueT{#1}{#1,}%
  #2)%
}
\makeatletter
\def\rmparenthesesaux(#1){\def\ProcessedArgument{#1}}
\def\rmparentheses#1{\rmparenthesesaux#1}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \RmParentheses #1
{
  \tl_if_head_eq_meaning:eNTF { #1  } (
  {
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_tail:n { #1 } }
  }{
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  }
  \tl_reverse:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_if_head_eq_meaning:eNTF { \l_tmpa_tl  } )
  {
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \tl_tail:N \l_tmpa_tl }
  }{
    \tl_set_eq:NN \l_tmpb_tl   \l_tmpa_tl 
  }
  \tl_reverse:N \l_tmpb_tl
  \tl_set_eq:NN \ProcessedArgument \l_tmpb_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\cmdfirst[(1,2)]{(3,4)}

\cmdfirst{(5,6,7)}

\cmdsecond[8,9,10]{11,12}

\cmdsecond{13,14,15}

\cmdthird[ (16,17)]{(18,19) }

\cmdthird{   20,21 }

\cmdthird[22,23)   ]{ (24,25,26  }
\end{document}

1We could also optimise this by testing for the optional argument first and stripping the parentheses only when it is present, but then we couldn't use the argument processor framework.
2I think?
3At least, not when I'm the user.
